# Self-inherited structure definition in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, vector, struct

What's the problem with the following structure definition and design ?
Can someone please explain a little bit what the following code does?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct A: public std:vector<A> 
{ 
   A(); 
   virtual ~A(); 
};

int main(){

   return 0;

}
```

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: can't you tell us what happens when you compile this? You say there's something wrong. What exactly?

Comment: First tell us *your actual problem* with it!

Comment: Look here: [CRTP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern), curiously recurring template pattern.

Comment: Right of the top your includes are wrong. Remove them both and include `vector`.

Comment: First of all, deriving from `std::` containers is *highly* discouraged.

Comment: Problem is, it should be `std::vector<A>` not `std:vector<A>`

Answer (score 0):

Silly mistakes are there. Use below code compiles in VS2013

```
#include <vector>

struct A : public std ::vector<A>
 {
    A();
    virtual ~A();
 };
```